Asian/Japanese found footage horror movie from 2000s with young women and a male ghost hunter
I'm looking for a movie I saw a couple years ago and cannot for the life of me remember the name or find it online. I'm positive that it was a horror film (I think it was a found footage movie) from Japan (J-Horror) made during the 2000's or 2010's. It's not Noroi: The Curse (2005), Paranormal Activity 2: Tokyo Night (2010), or Shirome (2010).
The main setting in the movie was a traditional Japanese house and the main characters were young women and a male ghost hunter. I believe it was haunted. The only scenes I remember were from the beginning and the end. I distinctly remember a scene in the beginning of the film in which a tentacled woman rises from the second story floor. The ending scene involved the ghost of a girl with a bob haircut talking to the person operating the camera. I also remember that random civilians would stop in front of the house and stare (like they were possessed).
So, what I definitely know:

It was Asian (most likely Japanese).
It was a horror movie (most likely found footage).
It was made during late 90s, 2000s, or early 2010s.


The movie is the found footage horror film "Cult" and here is the trailer (Good movie):




The film stars several idols who play themselves as they appear on a paranormal television show to investigate the exorcism of the Kaneda family. The supernatural events in the Kaneda household are recorded by the documentary team. A mysterious shaman seems to be the only hope of salvation not only for the family, but for the investigators as well.


The link in the answer above is broken. But the answer, the movie Cult by Japanese director Shiraishi Kōji, is likely correct. This one and a half minute trailer shows the tentacled entity rising from the floor around 1:06 in the clip.

It is Shutter (2004). I haven't watched this movie, as it is not available on internet anywhere. But to an extent it suits to this movie, as I have read its storyline on IMDb:

A young photographer Thun and his girlfriend Jane discover mysterious shadows in their photographs after fleeing the scene of an accident. As they investigate the phenomenon, they find other photographs contain similar supernatural images, that Thun's best friends are being haunted as well, and Jane discovers that her boyfriend has not told her everything. It soon becomes clear that you can not escape your past.


Possibly Shirome (2010)

Director Kôji Shiraishi wants to film an episode for a Japanese
  television program, featuring members of the "Idol"-genre singing and
  dancing ensemble, Momoiro Clover. The program is one wherein minor
  celebrity guests are employed to investigate haunted houses and
  similarly mysterious locales.

The members of Moroiro Clover are all young women.

Actually, I discovered Shirome when I was searching online for this movie. Unfortunately, that's not the movie I was looking for but the cast idea (mostly young women) is still the same. Thank you though!
